# Is an Immovable Rod a valid spellcasting focus?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, spellcasting

The Dungeon Master's Guide classifies an *immovable rod* as a rod rather than a wondrous item. Does this imply that it is a valid spellcasting focus? If not, what purpose does this classification serve?

Comment: The first part of your question, I believe, has been asked by the linked question in the banner. The second part ("If not, what purpose does this classification serve?") should be a seperate question.

Comment: Maybe this should be reworded, but the heart of my question is that no one I have ever seen uses the rod as if it's a spellcasting rod. It's always treated as a wondrous item device. Is the rod classification there to mark it as a spellcasting focus--the PHB makes clear not all rods are. See this question: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/129961/can-any-magic-item-rod-be-used-as-an-arcane-focus

Comment: I do not believe the linked question answers this question satisfactorily - Rod is listed as a type of arcane focus, which is the crux of this question.