# Do the bonuses from Artificer's Enhanced Arcane Focus and Staff of Power stack?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, spellcasting, stacking, artificer

When I have an Enhanced arcane focus wand in one hand and the Staff of Power in the other, do the spell attack bonuses stack?

> #### Enhanced Arcane Focus
>
> *Item: A rod, staff, or wand (requires attunement)*
>
> While holding this item, a creature gains a +1 bonus to spell attack rolls. In addition, the creature ignores half cover when making a spell attack.
>
> The bonus increases to +2 when you reach 10th level in this class.
>
> #### Staff of Power
>
> This staff can be wielded as a magic quarterstaff that grants a +2 bonus to attack and damage rolls made with it. While holding it, you gain a +2 bonus to Armor Class, saving throws, and spell attack rolls.

Comment: Does this answer your question: "[Do the Rod of the Pact Keeper and Wand of the War Mage stack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/83748)"

Comment: If the question linked by Medix2 answers the question for you we can close this as a duplicate and save everyone writing up a new answer when a good one already exists. Don't worry about your question being closed though, it will still be useful in letting others find that question.

Comment: Also, Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do the Rod of the Pact Keeper and Wand of the War Mage stack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/83748/do-the-rod-of-the-pact-keeper-and-wand-of-the-war-mage-stack)